# Change the size of the JDatePicker Calendar

Tags: java, swing, datepicker

I'm using `JDatePicker` to generate the calendar in java swing. I will like to change the font size inside of the calendar.

I have only manage to change the size of the displaying calendar panel but the font size display monday, tuesday, ...  failed to become bigger in size.

Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: [Which `JDatePicker`](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=jdatepicker&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=9yQFWtnEJ-TDXtfeouAH)?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jdatepicker/ this JDatePicker sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this **JDatePicker** library:

> https://sourceforge.net/projects/jdatepicker/

Then you can use **JFormattedTextField** to create a instance from JDatePicker and to set the font size, have a look at this code:

```
// Creating Date Model..
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model);
// Creating Date Picker
JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel);

// You can change font of JDatePicker like this:

JFormattedTextField textField = datePicker.getJFormattedTextField();
textField.setFont(new Font("sans-serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
```

Comment: Hi Rehan Javed, what you showed only change the text size of the the input text box of the Date panel. I was asking for the text size inside the pop up calendar. Thanks ;)

Comment: I don’t find anything in the documentation to increase the size of text inside the pop-up in JDatePicker, may he there is no any method to do it in current JDatePicker jar yet.